# capturing the form data inside the Angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I am new to Angularjs. I am having the form data which I need to make a post request to the server passing the data. I have done the UI and controller part inside the angularjs but do not know how to capture the form data. Please find the link to plnkr - [Plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/AUf1sDN0KXO0DDe1ksDZ?p=preview)

By clicking the add button, a new `li` element gets added and the same gets deleted when the minus sign is clicked. I need to get all the key value items into the below format for sending for Post request.

```
{
  "search_params": [
  {
    "key": "search string",
    "predicate": "matches",
    "value": "choosen text"
  },
  {
    "key": "search string",
    "predicate": "not-matches",
    "value": " search value"
  },
  {
    "key": "search string",
    "predicate": "matches",
    "value": " search value"
  }
]
```

}

How to capture the form data and construct the param object inside my controller inside the `searchParams` function inside the controller. Please let me know as I am new to Angularjs.

*Updated Question*
  Based on the inputs, I am able to get the user details in the controller. But there are few things:

- By default there will be one `li` element and when the user submits, the current `li` elements data should be captured in the controller.
- Only when I add the criteria using the plus button, the array is getting updated, but the last elements data is not being updated in the model when submitted.
- The same is holding good for the deleting the criteria too.

Link to updated Plunker - [Plnkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/VUUUow0auV4dVYvK9giQ?p=preview)

Comment: This might help you get going http://plnkr.co/edit/h1afP3TI2jrrYGQFUPOf?p=info

Comment: I verified your plunkr but some conditions not not working. Have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Chris Hermut and assuming you want an array of map, according to json you posted. You can do that by

```
 var arr = [];
  var form = {
    name: 'asd',
    surname: 'aasdasdsd',
    wharever: 'asd'
  }
  arr.push(form);

  //prentending to be another (key,value)
  form.surname = 'hfg';

  arr.push(form);
```

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v96gykvb/2/)  illustrating just that.

Answer (score 0):

Directives like `<select>`, `<input>` require ng-model attribute to correctly bind your input to $scope properties.

In your HTML markup you'll have to update your form elements with required attributes (like ng-model).

I would recommend (in controller/link) to use only one object for form data with different properties like

```
var form = {
    name: '',
    surname: '',
    wharever: ''
}
```

Corresponding `<input>` would be ex. `<input ng-model="form.name" type="text">`

After you have your 'form' object populated you can do JSON.stringify(form) before your request (if your using some other content-type then application/json).